# enclosure 要素のurl属性を取り出したい

Tags: javascript, jquery

**修正後の質問**
・下記の時、enclosure 要素のurl属性を取り出すにはどうすれば良いでしょうか？

```
var xml = '<foo><enclosure url="http://example.com" /></foo>';
var thisItem = $(xml);
console.log(thisItem.children('enclosure'));
```

---

**当初の質問**

```
console.log(thisItem.children('enclosure'));
```

・コンソール画面が、下記画像のような状態となりました

Q1
・この時、画像urlを文字列として取得したいのですが、どう書けば良いでしょうか？

Q2

```
typeof thisItem.children('enclosure');
```

・undefinedになりました
・これはノードリスト？
・今、どういう状態なのでしょうか？

コンソール画面画像

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: その thisItem はどうやって取得しましたか。

Comment: XML(?)として取得していると思います。「$.ajax({url: 'hoge.php',dataType: 'xml',」

Comment: `$.ajax()`は`jqXHR`オブジェクトを返すのでそのまま取得内容は見れないと思います。あと生JSに`children()`関数はないと思うのですが...

Comment: 取得したXMLを `$()` に渡してjQueryで扱っているのでしょうか。**その状況を再現できるデータやコード**を載せていただきたいですが…。

Comment: 外部データを取得しているため、状況を再現できるコード掲載は難しいです。誠に勝手ですが、この質問をクローズしていただけないでしょうか？　もうちょっと自分で調べてみて、質問内容を人に説明できるようになってから、再度検討したいと思います

Answer (score 5, accepted):

再現例としてはこんなところでしょうか。

```js
var xml = '<foo><enclosure url="http://example.com" /></foo>';
var thisItem = $(xml);
console.log(thisItem.children('enclosure'));
```

ここで `enclosure` 要素のurl属性を取り出したいのですよね。

XMLのテキストを `$()` 関数に渡した場合、（ブラウザがHTMLに対してするように）パース処理とDOMツリーの構築が行われ、ルート要素を選択した状態のjQueryオブジェクトが得られます。

ですから例えば `<img src="http://example.com" />` から src属性を取り出すのと同じように、jQueryの `.attr()` メソッドが使えます。

```
var xml = '<foo><enclosure url="http://example.com" /></foo>';
var thisItem = $(xml);
console.log(thisItem.children('enclosure').attr('url'));
```

上記のコードに `console.log(typeof thisItem.children('enclosure'))` を書き足せば、 `object` という文字列が出力されます。`undefined` は何かの間違いのような気がします。

ちなみに、jQueryオブジェクトはDOMの[Elementオブジェクト](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/API/Element)の配列に各種メソッドを足したようなオブジェクトです。ほとんどのメソッドは `.children()` のように再びjQueryオブジェクトを返すか、`.attr()` のように取得した値を返すかのどちらかで、`[0]` や `.get(0)` などを使って取り出さない限り NodeやNodeListなどのDOMのオブジェクトが直接現れることはありません。

Comment: thisItem.children('enclosure').attr('url')で希望結果を取得できました。console.log(typeof thisItem.children('enclosure')) で、 object を確認できました(undefined が表示されたと思ったのですが、勘違いでした)